# H2: Change schema of an existing table

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, flyway

It is possible to change the schema of an existing table in H2 ?

For example in my project I change the shema of table in Postgres with:

`ALTER TABLE my_table SET SCHEMA gestion;`

But in my test with H2 I have the error `expected "REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY";`

So I tried to disable **REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY** with

`ALTER TABLE my_table SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE;`

But there is no result and I have the same error.

Any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible for now, neither H2 1.4.200 nor H2 compiled from current sources supports that. The SQL Standard also doesn't define such operation, it is entirely vendor-specific.

You can only create a new table and copy content of old table into it (with `CREATE TABLE gestion.my_table AS TABLE my_table`, for example, but it will be safer to add the complete definition of the table to this command). You also need to create all constraints and indexes for the new table. If some other table references this table, you also need to update these references by yourself. After that you can drop the old table.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So you suggest to not use the command ```ALTER TABLE my_table SET SCHEMA gestion;``` in Postgres too ?

Comment: You can use this command in PostgreSQL. But H2 needs some other solution. You should avoid this command in PostgreSQL too only if you want to use exactly the same commands with both DBMS, but actually they also have many other differences, so if you really need to support them both, most likely you will need to write different SQL for them from time to time.